# how to use java map-reduce combiner on parallel stream

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency, mapreduce, java-stream

I have this java code that 
take strings (requests) get http response --> pass it to some comparison with old response saved in memory.

I want to collect n compare results into on Result object

and eventually I want to aggregate m report objects into one object.

I have this code

but I'm not sure if I'm doing the 2nd function

should I create new report each time?

How does the mechanism works?

```
        Report report = requestsList
                .parallelStream()
                .map(request ->
                                getResponse(request, e2EResultLongBL, e2EResultLongFresh)
                )
                .map(response -> compareToBl(response, e2EResultLongBL))
                .reduce(null,
                        (sumReport, compare2) ->
                        {
                            if (sumReport == null)
                            {
                                sumReport = new Report();
                            }
                            sumReport.add(compare2);
                            return  sumReport;
                        },
                        (report1, report2) ->
                        {
                            Report report3 = new Report();
                            report3.add(report2);
                            return report3;
                        });
```

edit

I have tried "collect" instead of "reduce"

I got this error:

```
Error:(174, 21) java: no suitable method found for collect(<nulltype>,(sumReport[...]rt; },(report1,r[...]t3; })
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super com.waze.routing.automation.dataModel.ComparisonResult>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R
        (argument mismatch; unexpected return value))
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<R,A>collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super com.waze.routing.automation.dataModel.ComparisonResult,A,R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,A
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Comment: Don’t use `reduce` this way. Learn about [`collect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)…

Comment: can you please explain why not?

Comment: `reduce` works on value-like classes and must not modify its input objects (it works best with immutable objects anyway). `collect` is exactly for solving the problem you have: you don’t want to unnecessarily create new `Report` instances, but only if required. What you want to do is a [“Mutable Reduction”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). As far as we can guess from your code example, something like `.collect(Report::new, Report::add, Report::add);` in place of your `reduce` operation should work…

Comment: where can i read why `reduce operation - must not modify its input objects` ?

Comment: Just follow the link I already gave you. Scroll upwards to see the “Reduction” section (and compare with the “Mutable Reduction”).

Comment: thanks! I will thought I don't want a collection<report> at the end. Just single aggregated one. So does it still fit to `collect` ?

Comment: `collect` is not limited to collections. If your `Supplier` creates `Report`s (like with `Report::new` as first argument), the result will be a `Report`. Compare with the example of [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499102/how-to-use-java-map-reduce-combiner-on-parallel-stream?noredirect=1#comment54792675_33499102)

Comment: thanks, can you please have a look at the exception I have added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94131/discussion-between-user1065869-and-holger).

Comment: The compiler error suggests that you are still using `null` as first argument. But it should be a `Supplier` which will determine the result type of the `collect` operation. As already said at the end of [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499102/how-to-use-java-map-reduce-combiner-on-parallel-stream#comment54792675_33499102), `Report::new` would be a good first argument for collecting into a `Report`.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a collector here.  You will be creating a report per parallel execution, adding the individual compare into the report, and then merging those reports with the final function.

No need to create a new report on the combiner.  Just add 2 to 1.

```
.collect(Collector.of(
    () -> new Report(),
    (report, compare2) -> {
       report.add(compare2);
       return report;
    },
    (report1, report2) -> {
       report1.add(report2);
       return report1;
    });
```

Also, if you want to make the code even cleaner, have the add function `return this;` You will be able to replace the lambdas with function references.

```
.collect(Collector.of(Report::new, Report::add, Report::add));
```